# wire up usb to pins rather than on board usb socket

Tags: arduino-uno, usb

I have an uno r3 clone in an enclosure and one [of these](http://cpc.farnell.com/cliff-electronic-components/cp30111/gender-changer-xlr-shell-usb-b/dp/CN19602?CMP=TREML007-005) usb ports on the enclosure.

It's pretty tight in there so I was wondering if there was a way to bypass the usb port on the board and plug it in directly to the pins.

So do something like plug the usb into the outer port on the enclosure and then cut off the usb end and plug the wires directly into the board rather than using the onboard arduino usb port.

The group of 4 just above the i2c seems promising but couldn't find much on it.

Thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at alternative (smaller) arduinos such as the mini?

Comment: Solder the wires to the underside of the usb socket. Option two; place the uno ne’er the edge of the enclosure and have the original socket stick out (you may have to desoldering the power jack to get it close enough to the side of the enclosure. Option three; get an uno clone with a micro usb jack instead of a regular B.

Comment: I did consider the mini and nano but attatching it to an enclosure is a little tricky. I have some pcb risers for the uno which fix perfectly and it is very secure in the enclosure. I'll give the underside a go first, removing the whole pcb block on the uno will be difficult.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to (optionally) desolder the existing USB socket and solder the wires to the pins where that socket was on the board. It connects directly to the pins of the CH340G surface mount chip (rectangular one by the USB socket) and soldering wires to those pins would be tricky.

Comment: Thanks for your help Majenko and Ratchet. I'll just desolder the usb port then.

Answer (score 2):

The USB actually goes through the 16 pin chip that will translate the USB to serial to the RX and TX pins. None of the external sockets or plated through holes are connected to the data lines of the USB port.

You are better off soldering the wire to the pins on the connector itself. Or try and find a proper wire with the correct connectors.